# Weird behavior with IE 11 when chart is displayed

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, internet-explorer-11

I am facing issue with IE 11. I am having few number of charts been displayed on it. Chart API used is RGraph. It is a javascript based chart API. For the first few times charts been displayed properly. But on refreshing the page for around 3-4 times, the some charts are not been displayed properly. It just shows blank space instead of chart. And when this behavior occur, other features which are been managed using css are not been displayed properly.

The same page works fine with IE 7, 8, 9, 10. This issue occurs only on IE 11.

No javascript error found on console. Doctype I have specified is `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

I think it is because of canvas tag this issue is occuring, do my guess is correct? If so then what is the way to solve it?

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Run your JavaScript through JSLint, to ensure there are no constructs in your code that might be (mis)interpreted by IE 11 that aren't by other browsers. IE 11 is more standards compatible than the older versions.

Does it work on other browsers?

Comment: Yes, it is working with other browsers. Only Internet Explorer 11 works it weirdly. JSLint, it requires to paste the code on are on the [site](http://www.jslint.com/). While the RGraph API I am using to plot charts, are dependent on other javascript libraries. So how to use it? Do I need to paste all libraries? I am not much aware about JSLint.

Comment: By the way, I have recently changed doctype. earlier it was `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`. With this doctype it was working fine with all browsers.

Comment: Strange. I believe <!DOCTYPE html> is the proper way to work with HTML5. It is good you got it working though, but I feel that this is an IE-11 quirk; maybe you can address this through a meta-tag that specifically targets IE-11? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e

Comment: It is working with other versions of IE, except IE 11.

I gone through the thread you have suggested. It states that the document mode in IE is started form version 8 and in version 11 it is deprecated. So, I don't think it is a good idea to use it. I have tried with Edge mode. Still facing the same issue.

Comment: Not working with `content="IE=10"` as well.